# App can't connect with graphql using graphql-java-kickstart

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, graphql, graphiql

I'm testing graphQL fucntional and have a problem: if I use libraries of com.graphql-java (graphql-spring-boot-starter, graphql-java-tools, graphiql-spring-boot-starter) Its work, but if I use GraphQL Java Kickstart (graphql-spring-boot-starter and so on) I catch 404 error.[GraphQL Java Kickstart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ppEuG.png) [com.graphql-java](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CIQrK.png)
In both cases application is sucssesfully started

My pom:
[pom](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Dvyb.png) Use java 11, spring boot 2.5.0 and maven 3.8.0
Commented dependency is my problem I think.Structure of .graphqls files and resolvers are working [file structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BhyR0.png) [resolver](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LlhR4.png) [service layer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ge5z0.png)
I have tried work with .properties file like [prop file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dcBos.png)
I need to connect GraphQL Java Kickstart because it has a lot of settings for graphql (work with exceprion handlers, dataLoader, pagination, depth of query and another problematic stuff, that has not at com.graphql-java)
Usung not last versions because want to test move  to new versions

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.